# No existe la propiedad en el Objeto

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

mi problema es que la app me funciona pero la consola me manda el siguiente error, cabe destacar que la app me que es una practica me funciona

> ExternoComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'first_name' of undefined

y el cygwin el siguiente

> ERROR in src/app/externo/externo.component.ts(20,27): error TS2339:
>   Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'.
>
> ```
> src/app/externo/externo.component.ts(21,28): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'.
> ```

y la verdad me estoy mareando porque no se si es un error mio o del navegador o de mi versión de angular o del compilador
este es mi service

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

    @Injectable()
    export class PeticionesService {
        public url:String;

        constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { 
            this.url='https://reqres.in';
        }

        getConfig(): Observable {
            return this._http.get(this.url+'/api/users/2');
        }
    }
```

y este es mi component

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { PeticionesService } from '../services/peticiones.service'

    @Component({
      selector: 'externo',
      templateUrl: './externo.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./externo.component.css'],
      providers:[PeticionesService]
    })
    export class ExternoComponent implements OnInit {
      public user:any;

      constructor(private _peticionesservice: PeticionesService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this._peticionesservice.getConfig().subscribe(
          result => {
            this.user= result.data;
            console.log(result);
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
      }

    }
```

Comment: Porqué estás asignando result.data a tu `this.user`? No debería ser `this.user = result;` ?

Comment: Falta el código de la plantilla (externo.component.html), pero el error que da el compilador es porque no has declarado el tipo de result en el servicio

Comment: Si estas seguro que data es una propiedad de result, puedes probar lo siguiente: **this.user= result['data'];** en lugar de **this.user= result.data;**

Answer (score 1):

Te está faltando la interfaz

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this._peticionesservice.getConfig().subscribe(
      (result: any) => {
        this.user= result.data;
        console.log(result);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

O mejor añun, declara la interfaz. Te dejo una referencia a una pregunta similar =)

[Como leer una variable especifica de un JSON en Angular](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/303847/como-leer-una-variable-especifica-de-un-json-en-angular/303849#303849)