# Como leer una variable especifica de un JSON en Angular

Tags: json, angular

Quiero leer una variable especifica de un archivo JSON en Angular. Lo puedo leer bien con HttpClient pero el compilador me da error cuando accedo a la variable especifica, sin embargo el sitio se renderea bien en el navegador y todo funciona bien a pesar de tener el error en el compilador de VSCode. Como puedo evitar este error.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
this.http.get('../../assets/config/configuration.json').subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res.serverIp);
});
```

}

El error es el siguiente: 
ERROR in src/app/services/options.service.ts(14,23): error TS2339: Property 'serverIp' does not exist on type 'Object'.

El error esta claro pero como logro evitarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te está fallando el typescript, tienes que especificar el tipo de dato que vas a recibir en "res" mediante una interfaz =>

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
this.http.get('../../assets/config/configuration.json').subscribe((res: any) => {
  console.log(res.serverIp);
});
```

o mejor aún, declara la interfaz para tu respuesta

```
export interface ConfigurationInterface {
  // Tus otras propiedades
  serverIp: string;
  // Tus otras propiedades
}

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.http.get('../../assets/config/configuration.json').subscribe((res: ConfigurationInterface) => {
    console.log(res.serverIp);
  });
```

Es altamente recomendable usar las interfaces, para usar a plenitud la potencia del typescript.